# Dialog fragment dialog not dismissing sometimes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am using a dialog fragment to show loading message when app is launched for first time.
I am using  public void show(FragmentManager manager, String tag)  method to display the dialog.

This loading message will be dismissed after data loading is done by intent service.
I am using dismissAllowingStateLoss() to close the dialog.

I didnt use dismiss() method as the app was crashing sometimes. But with dismissAllowingStateLoss(), the dialog was not being dismissed sometimes ( very rarely once in 100 times).

I have searched many blogs about this issue, but couldnt get the root cause.

Does anyone face such issue or have any idea about this kind of issue. Please suggest

Comment: With what error was the app crashing with a normal `dismiss()`?

Comment: if you can share your code, we may be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(yourFragment).commit();
```

If this doesnt solve the issue, please post some source-code so that we can try and assist you.